# Tauri local storage size

Tags: javascript, browser, local-storage, tauri

Is it possible to change the maximum size of the local storage (currently 5MB) on a Tauri App?

I know that different browsers have different maximum sizes for the local storage. i was wondering if we could configure it for the browser used on a Tauri app

Comment: As far as i know the WebViews don't have settings to change the max storage sizes :/